# How can I call a plugin in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create my first theme on wordpress by zero.
I add Disqus plugin to manage the comments for the post.

which is the standard function to call the plugin in post page?

my current post page looks like this:

```
    <?php
get_header('post');
//get_template_part( 'single-post-content' );
?>
<div id="slide1">

    <div class="article_content">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 50px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <div class="content">
        <?php the_post(); the_content(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php get_template_part('post_footer'); ?>
```

I'd like to display the comments box under each post 
how would you do it starting by zero?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the plugin's function.

To display the comments, you should call the [comments_template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/) function in your template and add a comments.php in your theme folder.

In the comments.php, you should call [comment_form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) to display the default WordPress form.

And after you activate the Disqus plugin, the plugin will replace the default WP comment form by some actions and filters.

You can refer to the default WordPress theme to know how to display the comments.
The code is in `twentysixteen/single.php` and `twentysixteen/comments.php`

**update**
If the plugin(Disqus WordPress) doesn't work well, you could manually install Discuz on your theme. Please refer to https://help.disqus.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1183281-manually-install-disqus-on-wordpress

Comment: Did you call comments_template?

Comment: If I use a standard wordpress theme it works fine.  the problem is with the theme that i create there must be something I'm missing

Comment: Please update your code in the question if you made some changes, so we could have more clues.

Comment: yes i call comments_template but i don't have the comments.php configured (there's nothing inside it)

Comment: i only add this two lines  <?php
  comments_template();
  comment_form(); ?>

Comment: I update the answer about how to manually install Discuz on WordPress.

Comment: I have tested on the default twentysixteen theme. When I comment out comments_template() in single.php, the Discuz comment part is gone. http://imgur.com/a/FCSDr